# ajax get works on localhost, not on live https site

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, https, get

I am calling an internal route of my app through an ajax get (no cross-site scripting)

```
Archive/WeatherForecast?lat=63.8299&lng=20.25484
```

It works great on my localhost, but on the live environment, where I have https, it throws me a "http 403, forbidden" error.

If it could have anything to do with the problem, that route makes a php request to

```
$api_url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecastlts/1.1/";
```

which is obviously not https, but the client shouldn't be concerned about that, because what is then served to the client is data from a file saved to disk (based on info from that http route above). I have checked the files produced and they are actual xml files with accurate content.

This is how the get request is done:

```
var url = '{{ path('WeatherForecast') }}';
var lat = $('#data_21').val();
var lng = $('#data_22').val();
var full_uri = url + '?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;
console.log('calling:' + full_uri);
jQuery.ajax({
     url:    full_uri,
     success: function(result) {
                $('#weatherdata').html(result);
            },
     error: function(result) {
                $('#weatherdata').html('kunde inte hämta väderdata');
            },              
    asynch: false,
});
```

Moreover, if I go into the chrome console to review the error, it shows me what route I tried to ajaxGet, and if I click on that route to open it in a new tab, it suddenly works and presents me with the data that the jQuery AjaxGet threw "403 forbidden" on...

It probably doesn't matter but it is a symfony2 app.

Comment: Is it `asynch: false,` or `async: false,`

Comment: and no comma at the end

Comment: I don't think you can do an http ajax request on https page. (for browser security reason)

Comment: @hendr1x is right about the comma, for IE, but that's not a cause for a 403 error.  Calling http from https may cause the browser to moan about insecure content, but wouldn't stop it working either.  This just sounds like a problem with a cross-domain ajax call.

Comment: but it is not a cross domain call. PSL is right, but changing it to async makes no difference. And like I said, no http data is served client-side, server-side that operation is made, but the client shouldn't be aware let alone concerned about that right?

Comment: @Archer: afaik cross-domain issues should arise as well from code run on localhost.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood.  Are you making a proxy call to `http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecastlts/1.1/`, but calling a local url to get that data then?

Comment: Maybe your server have a different configuration and your url `Archive/WeatherForecast?` is without `/` at end

Comment: I am doing a php file_get_contents() to the http route

Comment: https://mysite/app_dev.php/Archive/WeatherForecast?lat=63.8299&lng=20.25484 works fine in the browser, yet calling it through a ajax-get (asynch or not) is forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, sorry to have bothered you. I realized what the problem was... and the snippet with the problem is excluded from the question so you had no way of spotting it. Sorry.

Here it is: When trying out this code, I used a var_dump() followed by a die; to print out the data. That is apparently not a good enough response for the jquery/ajax engine in my live environment (although it works fine on my localhost).

Once I return a proper response object, it works.

This will generate an error status on the returned data if fetched with a jQuery ajax get:

```
    var_dump($weatherdata);
    die;
```

This will work fine (using symfony2 for creating the response)

```
    $response = new Response($r);
    $response->setCharset('ISO-8859-1');        
    return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [the docs for the webservice](http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecastlts/1.1/documentation), you are using the wrong url - try

```
http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecastlts/1.1/?lat=63.8299;lon=20.25484
```

Comment: Oh, no that IS the format I use in the file_get_contents(), but in my internal route I do standard querystring with & between values.

Comment: @MattiasSvensson: the name for the longitude parameter differs too (`lng` instead of `lon` from the api docs). but it appears that it doesn't matter ...

Comment: yup but that is just how I pass the data to my php function which in turn takes those values and makes a file_get_contents() to the correct url for the api.